# How to make bitmap transparent?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, opacity, transparent

```
/**
 * @param bitmap
 *            The source bitmap.
 * @param opacity
 *            a value between 0 (completely transparent) and 255 (completely
 *            opaque).
 * @return The opacity-adjusted bitmap. If the source bitmap is mutable it
 *         will be adjusted and returned, otherwise a new bitmap is created.
 *         Source : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392062/android-
 *         semitransparent-bitmap-background-is-black/14858913#14858913
 */
private Bitmap adjustOpacity(Bitmap bitmap, int opacity) {
    Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.isMutable() ? bitmap : bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
    int colour = (opacity & 0xFF) << 24;
    canvas.drawColor(colour, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN);
    return mutableBitmap;
}
```

Using `adjustOpacity`, I make `ImageView`'s `Bitmap` be semi-transparent.

```
Bitmap newBitmap = adjustOpacity(orignalBitmap, 10);
view.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

However, `Imageview` show more darkent before not white. How do I make a semi-transparent (white background) Imageview with `Bitmap`?

Answer (score 7):

```
// Convert transparentColor to be transparent in a Bitmap.
public static Bitmap makeTransparent(Bitmap bit, Color transparentColor) {
    int width =  bit.getWidth();
    int height = bit.getHeight();
    Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    int [] allpixels = new int [ myBitmap.getHeight()*myBitmap.getWidth()];
    bit.getPixels(allpixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(),myBitmap.getHeight());
    myBitmap.setPixels(allpixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    for(int i =0; i<myBitmap.getHeight()*myBitmap.getWidth();i++){
     if( allpixels[i] == transparentColor)

                 allpixels[i] = Color.alpha(Color.TRANSPARENT);
     }

      myBitmap.setPixels(allpixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());
      return myBitmap;
}
```

The above code will take a Bitmap, and return a Bitmap where every pixel which the color is transparentColor is transparent. This works in API as low as level 8, and I have not tested it in any lower.

I typically use something like Color.RED to make my transparent pixels, because I don't use a lot of RED in my assets, but if I do it's a custom red color.

Comment: `allpixels[i] == transparentColor` mmm.. Comparing a `Color` with an `Int`... I haven't tried tris, but I can see this will probably give an operator issue.

Answer (score 5):

Making an existing bitmap transparent is too simple.

If you want to make your bitmap transparent before further drawing follow this.

if your bitmap is mBitmap then Just use:-

```
mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
```

Thats it. Good luck !!

Answer (score 4):

Try this. Also note that setAlpha is in 0-255 range

```
//bmp is your Bitmap object

BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
bd.setAlpha(50);

ImageView v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
v.setImageDrawable(bd);
```

Comment: Thanks, I mean, i wanna change bitmap itself !

Comment: @vingorius     You should change question title then

Answer (score 1):

Add method

```
Bitmap bmp; DrawView DrawView;

private static Bitmap makeTransparentBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int alpha) {
        Bitmap transBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(),
                bmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(transBmp);
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAlpha(alpha);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);
        return transBmp;
    }


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(43,44,45));

    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mouse);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, pos_x, pos_y, null); 

}
```

You event:

```
bmp = makeTransparentBitmap( bmp, 122 );
DrawView.invalidate();
```

`DrawView` is

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    DrawView = new DrawView(this);
    setContentView( DrawView );
}
```

I found this answer [here](https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-code-snippet-to-create.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
newBitmap.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: do you mean 
    view.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);

Answer (score 0):

@akaya's answer is the right way except that the constructor is deprecated. The new way since API 4 would be to use:

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
drawable.setAlpha(100);
```